# How to get category name from post in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, categories

I am trying to get name and year from a post. This name and year was made as a category while making a post. It is not custom post.

I just want to retrieve the name and year. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a list of categories for a post you could use [wp_get_post_categories()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_categories/)

```
wp_get_post_categories( int $post_id, array $args = array() )
```

That call retrieves the list of categories for a post as an array of ID, so you can iterate with a for, foreach or while and then get the name of each category using [get_cat_name()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_cat_name/)

```
get_cat_name( int $cat_id )
```

So you could do something like:

```
<?php
// Get the array of categories ID from a post ID
$category_list = wp_get_post_categories($post_id);
$category_names = array();
// Add the name of each category to an empty array
foreach ($category_list as $category) {
    $category_names[] = get_cat_name( $category );
}
// Concatenate a string with the category names separated with commas.
$lister = implode(", ", $category_names);
```